# Store data on Blockchain via Backend App

Tags: web3js, nodejs

First of all, sorry about my bad english.

I looked in the forum but I did not find a similar situation, but I apologize if I'm repeating something here.

I need to develop an application that runs on my backend server, **without** Metamask, and write a hash in the transaction input data (or any other place I can retrieve later through the transaction address).

I'll only use one wallet, which I believe may have your information stored in my backend code. This wallet will only have the purpose of paying the GAS of the transactions.

Is this possible? I barely know where to start. I just know that I should develop this through web3.js and run through node.js, and everything I found tells me to use Metamask.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: which network are you using?

Comment: I need to do this on the mainnet. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is definitely doable using any Ethereum tech stack (Javascript, Python, Go, Java, etc...).

I will try to explain step by step how to do it using **nodejs**, **[Truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/truffle)** (Ethereum development framework) and **[Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache)** (local development blockchain)

**Prerequisite:**

- NodeJS, NPM
- Truffle

```
$ npm install -g truffle
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.0.24 (core: 5.0.24)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.3
Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37
```

- Ganache

```
$ npm install -g ganache-cli

$ ganache-cli --version
Ganache CLI v6.4.1 (ganache-core: 2.5.3)
```

**1. Initialise the Truffle project**

First step consists to create a new folder for our project and initialise the Truffle project.

```
$ mkdir blockchain-backend
$ cd blockchain-backend
$ truffle init
```

**2. Put your SmartContract into the `contracts/` folder**

I imagine from your question that your requirement s to store a hash on the Ethereum Blockchain, the following smart contract should simply do the job:

*DocRegistry.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

contract DocRegistry {

  struct Doc {
      address sender;
      uint date;
      bytes32 hash;
  }

  /**
   *  @dev Storage space used to record all documents
   */
  mapping(bytes32 => Doc) registry;

  /**
   *  @dev Store a document identified by its 32 bytes hash by recording the hash, the sender and date in the registry
   *  @dev Emit an event HashStored in case of success
   *  @param _hash Document hash
   */
  function storeHash(bytes32 _hash) external returns (bool) {
    registry[_hash].sender = msg.sender;
    registry[_hash].date = now;
    registry[_hash].hash = _hash;

    emit HashStored(msg.sender, _hash);

    return true;
  }

  /**
   *  @dev Definition of the event triggered when a document is successfully stored in the registry
   */
  event HashStored(address indexed _sender, bytes32 _hash);
}
```

Copy the file `DocRegistry.sol` into the folder `contracts/` of the Truffle project

**3. Configure the deployment**

To deploy a smart contract using Truffle, you need to add/edit two files:

- Migration Script

First, create a migration script into `migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js`

*migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js*

```js
const DocRegistry = artifacts.require("DocRegistry");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(DocRegistry);
};
```

- Truffle config

Then edit the file `truffle-config.js` and add the following code to connect to Ganache (development/testing blockchain)

*truffle-config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    }
  }
}
```

**4. Start the Ganache development blockchain**

Start Ganache

```
$ ganache-cli
Ganache CLI v6.4.1 (ganache-core: 2.5.3)
(...)
HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      pelican evolve ask syrup labor demand find weekend detect winner husband buffalo
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}
(...)
Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
```

*Save the Mnemonic for later*

**5. Deploy the smart contract**

To deploy the SmartContract on to Ganache (connection configured into `truffle-config.js`, run the following command.

```
$ truffle migrate
(...)
Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.00837372 ETH
```

**6. Create a NodeJS script to interact with the SmartContract deployed previously**

Now the important piece you are looking for is the way to interact with the Blockchain from a backend NodeJS.

- Initialise a NPM project

```
$ npm init
```

- Install dependencies

```
$ npm install truffle-contract truffle-hdwallet-provider --save
```

o [truffle-contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/truffle-contract): JS Ethereum contract abstraction

o [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider): HD Wallet-enabled Web3 provider. Use it to sign transactions for addresses derived from a 12-word mnemonic.

- Create the NodeJS script

The wallet used will be the one created by Ganache by default and formatted as a mnemonic, but any funded wallet could work.

Using truffle-contract, we can load the Truffle Artefact (JSON build file) which contains all the information about the smart contract and its deployment (address, , network, etc...)

```
  // Connect to the Blockchain and unlock the wallet to send transaction
  const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
  const mnemonic = "leisure chat amazing bleak erode olympic obscure chaos pull inquiry tunnel day"; // Wallet: 12 words mnemonic 
  const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://localhost:8545");

  // Load the Truffle artefact
  const truffleContract = require("truffle-contract");
  const DocRegistryJSON = require('./build/contracts/DocRegistry.json');
  const DocRegistry = truffleContract(DocRegistryJSON)
  DocRegistry.setProvider(provider);

  const docRegistryInstance = await DocRegistry.deployed();

  // Send transaction
  const hash = "0x644bcc7e564373040999aac89e7622f3ca71fba1d972fd94a31c3bfbf24e3938";
  var result = await docRegistryInstance.storeHash(hash, {from: "0x09b99dc4c7f7a1f6feffade28500e8f163e96d97"});

  console.log(result)
})();
```

**Result**

As a result, we get a transaction receipt

```
{ tx:
   '0x3a83e299d758c97a366e80d2887a66841f39320c2db685877caa1fc22fecdc23',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash:
      '0x3a83e299d758c97a366e80d2887a66841f39320c2db685877caa1fc22fecdc23',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash:
      '0x9556f8ac9736a6b6acffec39eb161486acd4525df308ebf152d9d6484b5af2f2',
     blockNumber: 9,
     from: '0x09b99dc4c7f7a1f6feffade28500e8f163e96d97',
     to: '0x17141b0c3b45b70f753d7c483558758bffdf6af4',
     gasUsed: 85727,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 85727,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ],
     status: true,
     logsBloom:
      '0x00000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000400001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
     v: '0x1b',
     r:
      '0xc8cd182b1a0b376e88bc4a6b4ea1d3c0571276e4027f20ec5ded420c5c60fe03',
     s:
      '0x0fc0d343f2782e13355ed2806352a1046e03eeb4eeb45ea53875614e01dc0a75',
     rawLogs: [ [Object] ] },
  logs:
   [ { logIndex: 0,
       transactionIndex: 0,
       transactionHash:
        '0x3a83e299d758c97a366e80d2887a66841f39320c2db685877caa1fc22fecdc23',
       blockHash:
        '0x9556f8ac9736a6b6acffec39eb161486acd4525df308ebf152d9d6484b5af2f2',
       blockNumber: 9,
       address: '0x17141b0C3B45b70f753d7c483558758BFFdf6aF4',
       type: 'mined',
       id: 'log_8a20c769',
       event: 'HashStored',
       args: [Result] } ] }
```

**Summary**

This a very simple example how to leverage Truffle to deploy a SmartContract and feed a NodeJS in order to execute calls, send transactions or listen events !

This example uses Ganache as a testing Ethereum Blockchain but could simply be replaced by any Ethereum nodes on any network (see [infura](https://infura.io/) for simple access to Ethereum networks: mainnet, ropsten, rinkeby, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, @greg-jeanmart! I read it and it makes a lot of sense. I'll try it and 
I'm going back here to give feedback.